# Validar una entrada con un arreglo unidimensional

Tags: java, array, poo

La idea es validar si el valor que doy en la entrada esta en el array unidimensional:

```
System.out.println("Ingrese el formato del video:" + "\n- MP4" + "\n- AVI" + "\n- MKV");
                formato = sc.next();
                for (int i = 0; i < formatoVideo.length; i++) {
                    if (formatoVideo[i].equals(formato)) {
                        formato = formatoVideo[i];
                    }
                }
```

Si la entrada que entra por teclado no hace parte del arreglo unidimensional, que no me deje avanzar hasta que digite una que si esté.

Comment: Por favor, muestra tu código completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es cuestión de que uses un ciclo repetitivo en este caso un do while, que repita la solicitud de ingreso de dato, en caso ingreses un valor diferente a alguno de los tres establecidos

```
    do{
    System.out.println("Ingrese el formato del video:" + "\n- MP4" + "\n- AVI" + "\n- MKV");
                    formato = sc.next();
                    for (int i = 0; i < formatoVideo.length; i++) {
                        if (formatoVideo[i].equals(formato)) {
                            formato = formatoVideo[i];
                        }
                    }
        }
    
 while(!formato.equals("MP4")&&!formato.equals("AVI")&&!formato.equals("MKV"));
```